# site is auto including some thing from other site

Tags: php

my site is automatically getting download from other site when ever i try to open my site after opening my site it trys to download any thing from this address....

google-sk.pch.com.tagged-com.superore.ru

please help me what's going on....

Comment: View source and search for "eval". Hopefully you won’t find any strange looking JavaScript. I'm just taking a guess that maybe you have been hacked because your post seems frantic. The eval() will usually have a Base 64 encoded string in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your site has been hacked. The site the address is pointing at is blocked in FIrefox as containing malicious code.

If this is it, you should take the site down, analyze what happened and change all your access passwords.

Maybe this helps a bit: [**Google Webmaster Central: My Site's been hacked: Now what?**](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/04/my-sites-been-hacked-now-what.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your site may have been compromised. Check .htaccess files, and crucial template or index files. For any unexpected code. You may also find a solution in restoring an archived version of your site.

You should immediately change passwords, and usernames. Use difficult usernames and passwords, consisting of many letters (varying case) and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your site has been hacked.

First change the password on your ftp access and review the security of your site, including database access.

Then go in and download what's on the site to a different area of your hard drive.

Compare this code against what you think should be there and remove any code you didn't create.

Also - as BlueRaja points out - check your database for corruption. If it has been compromised you'll probably have to restore it from backups.

Upload the corrected version (or just upload your backup).

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you are the victim of a [Cross-Site Scripting](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007-A1) hack.  Someone has added content to your site that contains HTML or Javascript tags, and when the content is displayed in a browser, it activates the browser to load more content from that site in Russia.

You should use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) when you echo any content that may have been contributed by users.  This translates any characters that might be dangerous to output verbatim, such as `<` or `>`, into their HTML entity equivalents (e.g. `&lt;` and `&gt;`) so that they can't affect browsers and are safely output as literal characters.

I would also search the database for any content that may have been contributed, that contains HTML or Javascript tags, and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check your database too!